# Android UDP hole-punching fails on second socket (Python+Java)

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, udp

I'm working on an Android phone app (`H`) that talks to a Peer, a RPi 3 (`P`), via UDP hole-punching. I have two sockets (`s` and `s_vid`) on H that will both be hole-punched thanks to a master server (`M`), and one socket (`S3` for clarity, but '`s`' in code) on `P`. H is on mobile network, P is on my wifi, and M is on Google Cloud Engine.

Program Flow:

---

`H` uses `s` to ping `M`, `M` sends addr/port info to `P`.

`H` uses `s_vid` to ping `M`, `M` sends addr/port info to `P`.

`P` uses `S3` to ping `M`, `M` sends addr/port info to `H`.

(we should now be hole-punched)

`H` uses `s` to send periodic packets to `P` on `S3`'s port.

`P` uses `S3` to send periodic packets to `H` on `s`'s port.

(all of this works fine with no issues...below is not working)

`P` uses `S3` to send periodic packets to `H` on `s_vid`'s port. (or, rather, it should).

---

So we should have 3 streams of packets: H@s -> P@S3, P@S3 -> H@s and P@S3 -> H@s_vid, but for some reason only the first two work. The last one hangs on the `s_vid.receive()` line (see code).

Here is the (relevant) code for H:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SensorEventListener{

    public String messageStr;
    public String masterMessageStr;
    public int master_msg_length;
    public int msg_length;
    public String masterMessageVidStr;
    public int master_msg_vid_length;

    public DatagramPacket p_peer;
    public DatagramPacket p_master;
    public DatagramPacket p_master_vid;
    public DatagramPacket p_rec;
    public DatagramPacket p_rec_vid;
    public DatagramSocket s;
    public DatagramSocket s_vid;

    public InetAddress return_peer_addr;
    public int return_peer_port;
    public InetAddress master_addr;
    public int master_port;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Define Sockets
        try {
            s = new DatagramSocket();
            s.setReuseAddress(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            s_vid = new DatagramSocket();
            s_vid.setReuseAddress(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            master_addr = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx");//hardcoded server address
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        master_port = 1111;//hardcoded server port


        //listen for server or peer packets.
        Runnable receive_thread_run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    p_rec = new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length);
                    try {
                        s.receive(p_rec);

                        //Do stuff...
                        //this works fine.
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        //listen for peer packets. PROBLEM IS HERE.
        Runnable receive_thread_run_vid = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                byte[] buf_vid = new byte[1024];
                p_rec_vid = new DatagramPacket(buf_vid,buf_vid.length);

                try {
                    s_vid.receive(p_rec_vid);//this is reached, but never receives...

                    //Do stuff...never reached.

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        //Start the threads
        Thread receive_thread_vid = new Thread(receive_thread_run_vid);
        receive_thread_vid.start();

        Thread receive_thread = new Thread(receive_thread_run);
        receive_thread.start();

        //Send out pings to master server for hole-punching.
        TimerTask return_master = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                masterMessageStr = "someping";

                master_msg_length = masterMessageStr.length();
                byte[] msg = masterMessageStr.getBytes();

                p_master = new DatagramPacket(msg,master_msg_length,master_addr,master_port);

                try {
                    s.send(p_master);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Timer return_master_timer = new Timer();
        return_master_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(return_master,1000,1000);

        //Send out pings to master server for hole-punching (2nd socket).
        TimerTask return_master_vid = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                masterMessageVidStr = "someotherping";

                master_msg_vid_length = masterMessageVidStr.length();
                byte[] msg_vid = masterMessageVidStr.getBytes();

                p_master_vid = new DatagramPacket(msg_vid,master_msg_vid_length,master_addr,master_port);

                try {
                    s_vid.send(p_master_vid);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Timer return_master_timer_vid = new Timer();
        return_master_timer_vid.scheduleAtFixedRate(return_master_vid,1000,1000);

        //Talk directly to the peer.
        TimerTask return_peer = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Do stuff...

                messageStr = "some peer-directed message";

                msg_length = messageStr.length();
                byte[] msg = messageStr.getBytes();

                p_peer = new DatagramPacket(msg,msg_length,return_peer_addr,return_peer_port);

                //check we know where to send it
                if (return_peer_addr != null && return_peer_port != 0) {
                    try {
                        s.send(p_peer);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Timer return_peer_timer = new Timer();
        return_peer_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(return_peer,500,500);//time in milliseconds
    }
}
```

Here is the (relevant) code for M:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import threading

## peer-Master UDP Comms
def receive_peer():#gets peer addr and sends it to phone.
    global peer_addr
    global peer_port

    while 1:
        data, addr = s_peer.recvfrom(1024)

        #figure out who is talking (should only be peer)
        if data == 'somepeerping':
            peer_addr = addr[0]
            peer_port = addr[1]

            #send it to phone
            if phone_addr is not None and peer_addr is not None and peer_port is not None:
                phone_ret_data = '{\"return_addr\":\"'+peer_addr+'\",\"return_port\":\"'+str(peer_port)+'\"}'
                s_phone.sendto(phone_ret_data,(phone_addr,phone_port))

## Phone-Master UDP Comms
def receive_phone():#gets phone addr (and phone vid addr) and sends it to peer.
    global phone_addr
    global phone_port
    global phone_addr_vid
    global phone_port_vid
    global peer_ret_data
    global peer_ret_data_vid

    while 1:
        data, addr = s_phone.recvfrom(1024)

        #figure out who is talking (whih of the two sockets)
        if data == 'someping':
            phone_addr = addr[0]
            phone_port = addr[1]

            if peer_addr is not None and phone_addr is not None and phone_port is not None:
                peer_ret_data = '{\"return_addr\":\"'+phone_addr+'\",\"msg_type\":\"novid\",\"return_port\":\"'+str(phone_port)+'\"}'
                s_peer.sendto(peer_ret_data,(peer_addr,peer_port))
        elif data == 'someotherping':
            phone_addr_vid = addr[0]
            phone_port_vid = addr[1]

            if peer_addr is not None and phone_addr_vid is not None and phone_port_vid is not None:
                peer_ret_data_vid = '{\"return_addr\":\"'+phone_addr_vid+'\",\"msg_type\":\"vid\",\"return_port\":\"'+str(phone_port_vid)+'\"}'
                s_peer.sendto(peer_ret_data_vid,(peer_addr,peer_port))

HOST = ''
PORT_peer = 2222
PORT_phone = 1111

peer_addr = None
peer_port = None
phone_addr = None
phone_port = None
phone_addr_vid = None
phone_port_vid = None

peer_ret_data = None
peer_ret_data_vid = None
phone_ret_data = None

## peer socket
try:
    s_peer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s_peer.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print("Socket created.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

try:
    s_peer.bind((HOST,PORT_peer))
    print("Socket binding complete.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    s_peer.close()
    sys.exit()

## Phone socket
try:
    s_phone = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s_phone.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print("Socket created.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

try:
    s_phone.bind((HOST,PORT_phone))
    print("Socket binding complete.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    s_phone.close()
    sys.exit()


## Initiate threads
threading.Thread(target=receive_peer).start()
threading.Thread(target=receive_phone).start()
```

Here is the (relevant) code for P:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import threading
import json
import time
import subprocess

## UDP Comms - thread to receive incoming packets.
def receive_thread():
    global master_addr
    global master_port
    global return_phone_addr
    global return_phone_port
    global return_phone_vid_addr
    global return_phone_vid_port
    global phone_packet_count

    while 1:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

        if addr[0] == master_addr and addr[1] == master_port:#message from master server, update return addresses
            master_msg_received = json.loads(data)
            master_msg_received = {str(key):str(value) for key,value in master_msg_received.items()}#to remove unicode

            if master_msg_received['msg_type'] == 'novid':
                return_phone_addr = master_msg_received['return_addr']
                return_phone_port = int(master_msg_received['return_port'])
            elif master_msg_received['msg_type'] == 'vid':
                return_phone_vid_addr = master_msg_received['return_addr']
                return_phone_vid_port = int(master_msg_received['return_port'])
        elif addr[0] == return_phone_addr and addr[1] == return_phone_port and return_phone_addr is not None:#message from phone
            phone_packet_count = phone_packet_count + 1
            msg_received = json.loads(data)
            msg_received = json.dumps(msg_received)#to remove unicode

            #Do stuff...no problems here or above.


## UDP Comms - threads to send out packets.
#send our address to master.
def ping_master():
    global master_addr
    global master_port

    s.sendto('somepeerping',(master_addr,master_port))
    threading.Timer(1,ping_master).start()

#return data to phone (for now packet count).
def return_phone():
    global return_phone_addr
    global return_phone_port
    global phone_packet_count

    if return_phone_addr is not None:
        s.sendto(str(phone_packet_count),(return_phone_addr,return_phone_port))

    threading.Timer(0.5,return_phone).start()

#send other data to phone on its second socket. POSSIBLE PROBLEM.
def return_phone_vid():
    global return_phone_addr
    global return_phone_port
    global return_phone_vid_addr
    global return_phone_vid_port

    if return_phone_vid_addr is None:
        threading.Timer(0.7,return_phone_vid).start()
    else:
        s.sendto('some second socket test ping',(return_phone_vid_addr,return_phone_vid_port))
        threading.Timer(0.7,return_phone_vid).start()


HOST = ''
PORT_phone = 0 #this is where phone comms arrive.

phone_packet_count = 0
return_phone_addr = None #this is where phone comms go.
return_phone_port = None #this is where phone comms go.
return_phone_vid_addr = None #this is where phone comms go.
return_phone_vid_port = None #this is where phone comms go.

master_addr = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx'#this is where master comms go. hardcoded.
master_port = 2222#this is where master comms go.
PORT_master = 0 #this is where master comms arrive.

## UDP Comms - initialize sockets.
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    print("Socket created.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

try:
    s.bind((HOST,PORT_phone))
    print("Socket binding complete.")
except socket.error, msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error: " + str(msg))
    s.close()
    sys.exit()

## Initiate threads
threading.Thread(target=receive_thread).start()
ping_master()
return_phone()
return_phone_vid()
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? I've already confirmed that `P` is receiving 2 different ports (same addr) for `s` and `s_vid`. I would expect both sockets to fail or none, not just one. Maybe a firewall issue? But again, why only one socket failing? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hole-punching error on my part. The punched sockets need to talk to each other directly. So in the style of my question, I had:

P@S3 -> H@s_vid but not H@s_vid -> P@S3 (I had both direction on the other socket). The fix is adding that direction to the phone app, akin to

```
TimerTask return_peer_vid = new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                retMessageVidStr = "test";

                ret_msg_vid_length = retMessageVidStr.length();
                byte[] msg = retMessageVidStr.getBytes();

                p_peer_vid = new DatagramPacket(msg,ret_msg_vid_length,return_peer_addr,return_peer_port);

                //check we know where to send it
                if (return_peer_addr != null && return_peer_port != 0) {
                    try {
                        s_vid.send(p_peer_vid);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Timer return_peer_timer_vid = new Timer();
        return_peer_timer_vid.scheduleAtFixedRate(return_peer_vid,500,500);//time in milliseconds
```